# Unable to get Axios "POST" data filed

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, axios

I am making an Axios "POST" request using front end:

```
  const res = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/chatGPT`,
    body: {
      chat: `hello how are you ?`,
    },
  });
```

I have a Node.js server running in the back end, so I am trying to print my `req.body` in the controller:

```
exports.test = async (req, res, next) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
    message: "done",
  });
};
```

But I am getting `req.body` as `undefined`. I am also using CORS.
But if I make Postman requests, it's working fine. Where am I going wrong?

Comment: Read the fine manual: https://axios-http.com/docs/api_intro

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your cors set it to `*`, to allow all.

Change your code to:

```
const res = await axios({
    method: "POST",
    url: `http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/v1/chatGPT`,
    data: {
      chat: `hello how are you ?`,
    },
  });
```

Comment: Yeah, this thing worked. Thanks !!. I've another doubt. I am getting the response as undefined. Any reason?

Comment: good, when my answer solve your issue , please make it as accepted

Comment: can you provide more infos or code to help you solving your issue

Comment: I am getting a response. I'm quite new to working with Axios. Thanks btw.